# Javascript regex not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex:

```
 /.*v\=([\w-]+).*(&autoplay\=1)?/
```

Which I am trying to match against:

```
 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awmLS6GCJno&width=1000&height=300&autoplay=1
```

This does not work. **(It matches the v=.. but not the autoplay=1)**

However, if I change my regex to:

```
 /.*v\=([\w-]+).*(&autoplay\=1)/
```

(no ? after autoplay), then it does match both.. (but now a URL without &autoplay won't get matched any more).. which is why I added the ? after that group.. Is that wrong? Is there another way?

Oops about that autofill title, obviously not the issue.

Comment: The problem is probably not caused by the RegExp.

Comment: I tested it with an online regexp tester and it does not match: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: I tested your first regex, with the link (both with and without `&autoplay=1`) and it matched both times. Tested this using expresso, and gskinner.com\regexr - therefore I conclude your problem is elsewhere!

Comment: @Jamiec I tested with regexr too, if you test the one with ? at the end, you will note that, whilst you hover over the matched URL, the second submatch is not available. (autoplay=1) is not matched, yet it is in the string..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your RegExp *does* work, but probably not as intended.

> `1. /.*v\=([\w-]+).*(&autoplay\=1)?/`
>   `2. /.*v\=([\w-]+).*(&autoplay\=1)/`

- The first RegExp has a quantifier `?`, which means: "Match none or once".
- This group is prefixed by `.*`, which means: "Match anything<sup>(except for newlines)</sup>, as much as possible.
- Because of the `?` quantifier, the RegExp is also valid when `&autoplay=1` isn't grouped (it will be matched by`.*`)

You're probably looking for this RegExp.

> `/.*v=([\w-]+).*?(&autoplay=1|$)/`

- `.*?` means: "Match anything<sup>(except for newlines)</sup>, as less as possible to get the RegExp match.
- `(&autoplay=1|$)` means: "Match `&autoplay=1` or the end of the string (`$`). If *end of the string* identifier is omitted, `.*?` would match NOTHING, because `.*?` is also valid for an empty string.

Comment: Quick question: If `.*` is greedy, why doesn't that `.*` at the start of the regex simply match any expression?

Comment: What if &autoplay=1 is not the end of the string? do I just change it to |.*) ?

Comment: No, `.*` will also be valid if nothing is matches, causing the RegExp to fail. You can delimit your pattern by characters which won't occur for sure: `(&autoplay=1|[^a-zA-Z0-9&=_-]|$)` will do.