# Why does this javascript regex literal not work?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

```
function fuzzQuery(rawQuery)
{
    re = /(?=[\(\) ])|(?<=[\(\) ])/;    

    strSplit = rawQuery.split(re);

    alert(strSplit);
};
```

Does not work (no dialog box).

I've check the expression at http://rubular.com/ and it works as intended.

Whereas

```
re = /e/
```

does work.

The input string is

`hello:(world one two three)`

The expected result is:

`hello:,(,world, ,one, ,two, ,three, )`

I have looked at the following SO questions:

[Javascript simple regexp doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845913/javascript-simple-regexp-doesnt-work)

[Why this javascript regex doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427731/why-this-javascript-regex-doesnt-work)

[Javascript regex not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804607/javascript-regex-not-working)

[Javascript RegEx Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521572/javascript-regex-not-working)

But I'm not making the mistakes like creating the expression as a string, or not double backslashing when it is a string.

Comment: javascript regex does not support lookbehind..  maybe an alternative here..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376238/javascript-regex-look-behind-alternative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the main issue with your regular expression is that [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) does not support **Lookbehind**.

```
re = /(?=[\(\) ])|(?<=[\(\) ])/
                   ^^^ A problem...
```

Instead, you could possibly use an alternative:

```
re       = /(?=[() ])|(?=[^\W])\b/;
strSplit = rawQuery.split(re);
console.log(strSplit);

// [ 'hello:', '(', 'world', ' ', 'one', ' ', 'two', ' ', 'three', ')' ]
```

Comment: Lame. Any suggestions?

Comment: @dwjohnston I added a possible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this :

```
re = /((?=\(\) ))|((?=[\(\) ]))./;    

    strSplit = rawQuery.split(re);

    console.log(strSplit);
```